# Chartjs Bar Chart Not Working?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart using Chartjs. I'm pulling numbers from my database and this is what get logged when I print them to the console:

```
tv: 9,186 ti: 718 tu: 2,231 ts: 2,922 tl: 7,393  
mv: 9,186 mi: 718 mu: 2,231 ms: 2,922 ml: 7,393
wv: 3,114 wi: 718 wu: 2,231 ws: 2,922 wl: 7,393
dv: 113 di: 69 du: 83 ds: 129 dl: 361
```

These are the expected numbers. If I hardcode these in to my data object to bass in to chartjs, everything works properly. If I put the variables in the data array, it does not work properly. Here is my code trying to use my variables:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Views", "Infusion Calculations", "User Searches", "Character Selections", "Light Calculations"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Today",
            fillColor: bc1,
            strokeColor: bc1,
            highlightFill: bc1,
            highlightStroke: bc1,
            data: [dv, di, du, ds, dl]
        },
        {
            label: "Past Week",
            fillColor: bc2,
            strokeColor: bc2,
            highlightFill: bc2,
            highlightStroke: bc2,
            data: [wv, wi, wu, ws, wl],
        },
        {
            label: "Past Month",
            fillColor: bc3,
            strokeColor: bc3,
            highlightFill: bc3,
            highlightStroke: bc3,
            data: [mv, mi, mu, ms, ml],
        },
        {
            label: "All Time",
            fillColor: bc4,
            strokeColor: bc4,
            highlightFill: bc4,
            highlightStroke: bc4,
            data: [tv, ti, tu, ts, tl],
        }
    ]
};

var barchart = new Chart(todaybar).Bar(data);
```

I am also logging the object created by Chartjs, and it looks like it has all the data sets in properly.

You can view the issue [here](http://mattaltepeter.com/destiny/analytics.php), as well as view the logged data in the JS console.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Those values you're passing in for the data look like strings, not numbers. Chart.js *might* be willing to convert them to numbers, but the values with commas are not going to work.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah, I'm running `.toString()` and a `.replace()` to add the comma in. That was mainly for when I was just printing them out, but shouldn't be as much of an issue now that I'm converting them to bar charts

Comment: @Pointy yuppp. That did it. Thanks!